# Are two function pointers that are not exactly the same ever compatible?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, undefined-behavior

I have these function pointer types:

```cpp
typedef int(*a)(char*);
typedef const int(*b)(char*);
typedef int(*c)(char* const);
typedef int(*d)(const char*);
typedef long(*e)(char*);
typedef int(*f)(unsigned char*);
typedef void(*g)(char*);
```

I know that `a` and `c` are exactly the same (at least in C++), as the `const` is ignored in function prototype argument types.

My question is if I have a variable of type `a`, and another variable of any of those 7 types, which of them would I be able to assign to the first variable?

```cpp
a foo = NULL;
(a/b/c/d/e/f/g) bar = ...;
foo = bar;  // Is this UB based on the type of bar?
```

Would I be able to detect it?

I tried taking advantage of how [`template<class F> ::std::function::operator=(F&&)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator%3D) is defined, as "This operator does not participate in overload resolution unless f is Callable for argument types Args... and return type R."

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class U>
static void _print_is_assignable(const char* const t_name, const char* const u_name) {
    using function_t = ::std::function<typename ::std::remove_pointer<T>::type>;
    std::cout << t_name;
    std::cout << (::std::is_assignable<function_t&, U>::value ? " == " : " != ");
    std::cout << u_name << '\n';
}

#define PRINT_IS_ASSIGNABLE(T, U) _print_is_assignable<T, U>(#T, #U)

typedef int(*a)(char*);
typedef const int(*b)(char*);
typedef int(*c)(char* const);
typedef int(*d)(const char*);
typedef long(*e)(char*);
typedef int(*f)(unsigned char*);
typedef void(*g)(char*);

int main() {
    PRINT_IS_ASSIGNABLE(a, a);  // a == a
    PRINT_IS_ASSIGNABLE(a, b);  // a == b
    PRINT_IS_ASSIGNABLE(a, c);  // a == c
    PRINT_IS_ASSIGNABLE(a, d);  // a == d
    PRINT_IS_ASSIGNABLE(a, e);  // a == e
    PRINT_IS_ASSIGNABLE(a, f);  // a != f
    PRINT_IS_ASSIGNABLE(a, g);  // a != g
    PRINT_IS_ASSIGNABLE(g, a);  // g == a
}
```

Comment: Since all function pointers are pointers, they have the size of void*. Therefore, techically you can cast the one to another. Introducing, undefined nehaviour when casts are wrong.

Comment: @Michael Only value pointers can be cast to `void*`. Function pointers can not be safely cast to `void*`, and also even if they could, I doubt reinterpreting them and then calling them wouldn't crash. I want to know if I could still run the function through a slightly different type.

Comment: C has a normative concept of type compatibility, but C++ approaches it differently. Honestly, pulling C into this just overly broadens the question, and for no reason. Your query about C is a footenote at best. While a through treatment of the subject will be fairly long.

Comment: The problem with calling functions is that this is dependent on the ABI. Since there is no ABI explicitly defined as part of the standard there is no way to understand how it would work in general. If you know and understand the ABI then you understand how it would work.

Comment: @Michael Not true. In general, "they're the same size, therefore I can cast between them" is an unsafe way to program C++.

Comment: @Michael: There is no requirement that function pointers hold anything resembling addresses.  It would be perfectly legitimate (and for some purposes actually a good idea) for function pointers to hold indexes into address tables or jump tables.  On many 8-bit processors, for example, dispatch via 8-bit function selectors would be faster than dispatch via 16-bit function pointers.  On larger machines, using indices would make it easier to trap attempts to make calls via invalid pointers.

Answer (score 3):

I've read the spec a bit, and the closest thing I could find is in section 5.2.10 `[expr.reinterpret.cast]`:

> A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type. The effect of calling a function through a pointer to a function type (8.3.5) that is not the same as the type used in the definition of the function is undefined. Except that converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are function types) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value, the result of such a pointer conversion is unspecified.

Which seems to tell me that, no, it is undefined behaviour, unless the function pointer types are exactly the same, and I would have to cast back to the original type.

With some testing, g++ doesn't seem to mind if pointers are returned what pointers are returned, and if the return type is `const` qualified doesn't matter, which makes sense. I would just have to use `std::function` when trying to deal with almost compatible types.

Comment: FWIW, this is a perfectly good answer and you did not have to make it CW!